# Kerning a particular pair like "(j"

Tags: xetex, kerning

In my math document, I often use `(j` and in my current math font, the `(` runs into the `j`. I don't really have problems with kerning elsewhere. I could replace `(j` by `(\mkern2mu j`, but is there a way to do this globally?

(I don't think it will matter, but I'm compiling with XeLaTeX.)

Comment: as a side node, I guess `j` is supposed to be the imaginary unit? In that case it should be upright, or even better, defined as a mathematical operator. That should solve the kerning issue as well.

Comment: @thewaywewalk No, I don't use `j` as the imaginary unit, but my math font is already upright and I still have issue with `(j`.

Answer (score 16):

Because XeTeX character classes do not work in math mode (?) the only way to tackle this is by defining the opening parenthesis math active and check whether the next token is `j` before inserting the kern.

The advantage is that the following solution is engine agnostic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\lparen=\mathcode`\(
\begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`\(
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{\lparen\@ifnextchar{j}{\mkern2mu}{}}%
  }%
\mathcode`(="8000
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\lparen j$

$(j$
\end{document}
```

Above is the original, below with kern.

[image]

---

The above solution is not compatible with the `amsmath` package.  To work with `amsmath` one needs to employ a different solution, which might be less desirable.  We define `\lparen` to typeset an opening parenthesis and to look ahead for `j`.  For symmetry reasons we also define `\rparen` which is just `)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\lparen{(\@ifnextchar{j}{\mkern2mu}{}}
\def\rparen{)}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$(j)$

$\lparen j \rparen$

$\left( j \dfrac{a}{b} \right)$

$\left\lparen j \dfrac{a}{b} \right\rparen$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Fix for `amsmath` (works also for `unicode-math` and `lualatex` and legacy fonts); the problem is that `amsmath` uses `(` for its `\resetMathstrut@` macro, so we need to substitute it with `\lparen`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
%\usepackage{unicode-math} % try with xelatex or lualatex also uncommenting it 

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\ifx\Umathcharnumdef\@undefined
  \mathchardef\lparen=\mathcode`\(
  \patchcmd\resetMathstrut@{\mathcode`\(}{\lparen}{}{}%
\else
  \Umathcharnumdef\lparen\Umathcodenum`\(
  \patchcmd\resetMathstrut@{\Umathcodenum`\(}{\lparen}{}{}%
\fi
\begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`\(
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{\lparen\@ifnextchar j{\mkern2mu }{}}%
  }%
\mathcode`(="8000
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\lparen j$

$(j$

$\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see possible issues with `\left(` and `\bigl(`. Did you try them?

Comment: @egreg Because `\lparen` is the first token in the replacement text, it is correctly picked up by `\left`, but you lose the look-ahead functionality due to the parenthesis being encapsulated in a `\mathopen` atom.  If you do it right though, you use `\left` and `\right` only for large delimiters (and not all the time) and for these you don't need additional kerning :-)

Comment: @egreg Further investigations showed, that `(` is not even active when used with `\left`.  I wonder what `\left` is doing to the succeeding token.

Comment: It uses its `\delcode`, so long as it's a character with category code 11 or 12. I just wanted to be sure you thought to the implications. Anyway, I fixed a (not so minor) glitch.

Comment: @egreg Making a character active in general shows a lack of thinking about the implications ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get `! Bad character code (2097151).`, a minimal example being the code of your answer together with `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Unfortunately, `amsmath` is not compatible with this solution due to [internal limitations](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31408578#31408578).

Comment: Thank you for the link to the discussion in chat. Not being able to use your code together `amsmath` is indeed a limitation... I upvoted your answer, but I think I will keep using `amsmath` over fixing the kerning for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Earthliŋ You could turn it around and define `\def\lparen{(\@ifnextchar{j}{\mkern2mu}{}}`.  Then you'd have to use `\lparen` instead of `(`, but this way you work around the bug and it even works with `\left .. \right`.

Comment: Hm... I'll consider it, but I also copy/paste parts of my code when collaborating with other people, so I try to use as few macros as possible. I wouldn't be happy to receive code that uses macros for parentheses.

Comment: The last code does not compile with `xelatex`. The error message is *! You can't use `\Umathchar"4"0"28' after \the. <recently read> \lparen*.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Blame egreg, he edited my answer to include this.